# How do I apply "values_at" to an array of arrays in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, each

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  If I want to extract certain elements from an array at indexes I specify in another array, I can do

```
2.4.0 :012 > arr.values_at(*indexes)
 => ["a", "e", "g"]
```

But if I have an array of arrays, how would apply the above to each array in the array of arrays?  I tried this

```
2.4.0 :014 > arr_of_arrays.map( &values_at(*indexes) )
NoMethodError: undefined method `values_at' for main:Object
```

Also I would like the result to be a new object, as opposed to modifying the original object in place.

Comment: Are `*indexes` fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use symbol to proc with a parameter.

```
arr_of_arrays.map { |a| a.values_at(*indexes) }
```

One possible workaround is modifying the `Symbol` class, but this practice is highly frowned upon.

```
class Symbol
  def with(*args, &block)
    ->(caller, *rest) { caller.send(self, *rest, *args, &block) }
  end
end
```

With this you can pass parameters.

Comment: if you really love this patch you can load it with refinements then it won't be frowned upon as much.